# MongoDB: Error parsing command line: unrecognised option '--sslMode'

Tags: mongodb, ssl

So being completely new to the NoSQL world, I decided to give mongodb a trial, and downloaded the following version, which I presumed supported ssl out of the box:

```
db version v3.2.4
git version: e2ee9ffcf9f5a94fad76802e28cc978718bb7a30
allocator: tcmalloc
modules: none
build environment:
    distarch: x86_64
    target_arch: x86_64
```

So when I run

```
mongod --sslMode requireSSL --sslPEMKeyFile C:\data\keys\server-key.pem --sslCAFile C:\data\keys\ca-crt.pem
```

I get the following error message:

> Error parsing command line: unrecognised option '--sslMode'
>
> try 'mongod --help' for more information

What am I missing here?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg I'm using Windows Pro 10.

Comment: The Windows binaries of MongoDB do not support SSL, afaik. SSL-enabled versions have an according notice (on the download page), which the Windows versions are missing. Furthermore, I can not suggest running MongoDB on Windows for production anyway.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Mongo will only be run on the windows machine for development purposes. 

I'll try and locate a pre-built mongo/ssl package.

Comment: Why would you need SSL for dev purposes?

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg  Because that is what my production environment will be based upon. I have zero desire to wait until migrating to a  production environment, before ascertaining whether all is functioning as expected.

Comment: Imho, this should be covered in integration tests, which are supposed to resemble the production env as closely as possible. And I still do not get the point in running it on a Windows machine, even during dev. If TLS is of such importance, I'd use a VM or use Linux right away. Maybe I am missing something, but the world usually does not bent for special wishes.

Comment: Actually, I'm getting the same error message on an ubuntu 14.04 prod server using the command:

# mongo --ssl --sslCAFile /etc/ssl/uls-prod.chain.cert.pem --sslPEMKeyFile /etc/ssl/mongo-client.chain.cert.pem
Error parsing command line:  Multiple occurrences of option "--ssl"
try 'mongo --help' for more information

running as root...perms are all ok ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Faced the same issue while working on mongo-university's M001: MongoDB Basics course.
The demo connection for the course expects a ssl connection but the mongo binary I had threw this error:

```
$ mongo "mongodb://primary:27017,replica1:27017,replica2:27017/test?replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0" --ssl --authenticationDatabase admin --username <user_name> --password <password>
Error parsing command line: unrecognised option '--ssl'
try 'mongo --help' for more information
```

Root cause of the issue is that the `mongo` binary provided in the `community` edition does not support `--ssl` option.
I downloaded the evaluation version for the enterprise edition and connected successfully the M001:demo mongo server.

More details are in mongo Jira issue [SERVER:21622](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-21622?focusedCommentId=1095856&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-1095856)

Answer (score 2):

**The selected answer is no longer valid**. At the official docker images 4.2.0. (latest right now) and 4.0.1. from Dockerhub you can set the flags --sslMode respectively --tlsMode (Haven't tested other image tags).

Prerequisites

```
sudo docker volume create --name mongo-cert
LOCATION="$(sudo docker volume inspect mongo-cert | jq -r '.[0].Mountpoint')"
sudo openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout "$LOCATION/key.pem" -out "$LOCATION/cert.pem" -days 365 -nodes
touch $LOCATION/mongo.pem
cat $LOCATION/key.pem >> $LOCATION/mongo.pem
cat $LOCATION/cert.pem >> $LOCATION/mongo.pem
```

v4.2.0

```
sudo docker run --name mongo --rm -p 27017:27017 --mount source=mongo-cert,target="/cert" \
mongo:4.2.0 mongod \
--tlsMode "allowTLS" \
--tlsCertificateKeyFile "/cert/mongo.pem"
```

v4.0.1

```
sudo docker run --name mongo --rm -p 27017:27017 --mount source=mongo-cert,target="/cert" \
mongo:4.0.1 mongod \
--sslMode "allowSSL" \
--sslPEMKeyFile "/cert/mongo.pem"
```